# Exchange Web Services (EWS) get events calendar via ASP page & C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

I look for a way to recover calendar events from an Exchange server 2010 (EWS) via a web page ASP.net & C #.

If someone have an idea or a link that I can use because the only links I found are for console applications in C # not via a website ASP.

I already have the class in C# but I do not know how to implement this code via a ASP.net web page

thank you in advance

Comment: Why should it be any different to do it from a console application or from an ASP.Net page?

Comment: Someone correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe that the Calendar Color is just a random extended property that different Clients use. E.g. [Outlook 2003](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/exchange/en-US/067faef0-9968-40b8-a620-a6045500a9c3/how-to-get-outlook-2003-calendar-color-through-ews) uses a different attribute from Outlook 2010, and so on.